# ASP.net MVC Attribute not executed in overridden controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes

I have a custom attribute which is executing correctly when used in a method in my controller.

My Controller "A" is inheriting from Controller "B" and Controller "A" is overriding one of the method of Controller "B". I have my custom attribute applied to that method but it's not executing at all. I tried putting in the base method as well but still same.

As noted earlier, the custom attribute is executing as expected if applied in methods that is not overriding.

Am I missing anything?

Attribute is executed for the following action method:

```
    [RequireAuthorizationFor(Operation.Create)]
    public ViewResult New()
    {
        return View("Edit", new TermDateDto());
    }
```

But not for the following:

```
    [RequireAuthorizationFor(Operation.List)]
    public override ViewResult List(Query query, int? pageNo)
    {
        return base.List(query, pageNo);
    }
```

Comment: Re comment: again, does `RequireAuthorizationForAttribute` have `Inherited=true`

Answer (score 2):

If it is a custom attribute, is it set to inherit = true?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true)]
```

Also; perhaps side-step the issue; don't make the public attributed method `virtual` - instead make it *call* a `protected virtual` method. A little abstraction goes a long way.

Comment: hi marc, 

i have updated the question with code sample. 
thanks